# how to access @EnvironmentObject in view's init()

Tags: swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
//    @ObservedObject var user = User()
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    
    init(){
        user.username = "yy"
    }
```

I want change EvironmentObject value in init()
cuz I want data preprocessing

but this code has error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type User found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for User may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

how can I access EnvironmentObject in View's initialize?

Comment: Is there any place that you coded
```
let user = User()
ContentView().environmentObject(user)
```